# How do I expect the page loads to execute the next command in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I need to fix this problem. I have tests in protractor, but they fail because the commands execute before the page loads. I used sleep function to try to solve this problem, but this is not the better way and in some moments this fails too.
I tried the following global function, but in some moments the error "Element is not clickable at point (39, 109). Other element would receive the click:" is displayed to me, even the button has been clicked:

```
global.waitForElementToBeLoaded = function(locator, identifier){
    var elementToFind = locator(identifier);
    browser.wait(function(){
        return        browser.driver.isElementPresent(elementToFind).then(function(found){
        return found;
});
}, 60000, "The test execution timed out waiting for " + elementToFind);
     expect(browser.driver.isElementPresent(elementToFind)).toBeTruthy();
     return browser.element(locator(identifier));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused with your code snippet. Shouldn't wait timeout and msg be inside `browser.wait`

```
browser.wait(function(){
        return  browser.driver.isElementPresent(elementToFind).then(function(found){
           return found;
              }, 60000, "The test execution timed out waiting for " + identifier);
```

Also sometimes just `isElementPresent` is not enough, you may need to couple it up with `isDisplayed()`, like below. Unfortunately there is no once size fits all condition for waits, sometimes you may want to wait for visibility of element, sometimes invisibility, click-ability etc. `selenium-webdriver` provides [many useful methods](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/namespace_webdriver_until.html) as part of `until` object you can leverage them on case by case basis.

```
browser.wait(function(){
            return  browser.driver.isElementPresent(elementToFind).then(function(found){
               if(found) {
                 return browser.driver.isDisplayed(elementToFind).then(function(displayed) {
                     return displayed;   
                  }
               } 
                return found;
    }, 60000, "The test execution timed out waiting for " + identifier);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be useful in those kind of situations where I need something to happen after the page loads.

`browser.wait(protractor.until.titleIs("Some Page"), 10000,
        "✗ Failed to wait for the page to load").then(function(){
            // DO Stuff
        });`